# Function not called after location.reload() or location.reload(true)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling location.reload on a resize event, but I expect the function to be called every time the page is reloaded.

console.log("resize called") is called, but console.log("Function called") is not. What's going on?

```
function sayHello(){
    console.log("Function called");
}

sayHello();

$(window).resize(function () { 
    console.log("resize called");
    location.reload(true);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you ever completely reload the page on a resize ?

Comment: Your code just works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/yto9s81k/

Comment: @MangeshParte: It works in some browsers. IE and Chrome runs the function, Firefox doesn't.

Comment: Try using window.location.reload();

Comment: Yep, I'm currently testing with FireFox. 

@adeneo I'm doing this because I'm having some issues rescaling a canvas chart on resize. Calling the functions in the resize messes things up. Resizing and then reloading displays the chart correctly. So I was like, meh -- The odd time the user resizes the window, I'll reload the page instead.

Comment: window.location = window.location will work, but I will lose any post data :(